# Calculator on 4.2.2 lockscreen?

Tags: lock-screens, sprint, calculator

I'm wondering if it's possible to put the calculator app on the 4.2 lockscreen (similar to how the camera is there). Not a widget, but the app. I'm running the latest CM10.1 nightly, on a Sprint GS3.

Thanks!

Comment: The only things you can add to the lockscreen are lockscreen widgets. A quick [search on the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=lock%20screen%20widget%20calculator&c=apps) offers quite a few possibilities.